Grid network - Colombian Sudoku
This is a new Colombian Sudoku that I really enjoyed creating. The rules are the same as always: fill the Sudoku on the left, using the clues on the right. The number of points in a row of the table indicates how many matches it has with the corresponding row of the completed Sudoku.


This is my first time answering a post, so I apologize for weird formatting things. I did my best!
Completed grid:

198|637|542643|852|971257|941|836-------------436|795|218582|316|497719|284|365-------------824|163|759965|478|123371|529|684

First, match the given clues from the left board to the right board and eliminate any clues on the right-hand board that are made illegal by them, as well as all clues in column 4 since there are no matches.

 

Next look at the right-hand board clues.

In C1 there are 5 matches, and 5 distinct clues remaining. We can immediately place the 1,2, and 9; we don’t know where the 6 or 7 will go yet. Similarly in C2, we can place the 9. Additionally, we see that in column 2 the 7 must be in the bottom box, meaning we can eliminate the 7-clue in R7C1. This now allows us to place the 7 in C1R6. Next, C5 has 5 matches and 5 clues, so we can place them all right away and finish off the column. After we clean up the right-hand board from those matches, we can place the 1 and 9 in C6. 

Similarly if we look at the row clues,

we can immediately place the 2 in R4 because there are 2 matches remaining and 2 distinct clues (we don’t know yet where the 6 will go). Same goes for 9 and 3 in R6. 

Now, a quick observation:

The 5 in R5C1 forces the 5 in the middle-right box to be in C9. This allows us to eliminate the 5-clue in R3C9, and then we can place the 8 in R3 as well as the 2 and 4 in C9. 

Now,

there are 3 matches left in C3, and 3 distinct clues. We can place the 4 and 6. This forces the 6 in C1 to go in the top-left box, and the 4 in C1 must go in R4. We can also place the 4 in R2C2, which means the last match in R2 must be the 3. We can also place the last match in C7 (the 6). 

Next,

look at the center box. The 2 must be in the left column (C4). The 2 in the right box prevents it from being in R4, and there is a crossed-out 2-clue in R5. Therefore it must go in R6. Then we can finish off R6 using Sudoku rules. Additionally, we can fill the 9 in top-middle box. We can also finish off the top-left box by remembering that R3C2 cannot be 7 due to the right-hand clues in the bottom left box. 

A few more Sudoku deductions:

(Note:To fill in the 4 and 5 in R1, note the crossed-out 5-clue on the right-hand board.) 

Finally,

Now we can place the last remaining clue in C8 (the 5), which also allows us to finally place the 7 in C2, finishing off the right-hand board. 

From here it's basic Sudoku solving.
This was fun! Thanks for posting the puzzle!
